# How to resume a page which is already opened in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, onresume

How to resume a page which is already opened in WP7?

For example : In P1 there are two buttons A and B,when i click A it takes me to P2 and when i come back to P1 and again click A it not working. But after i click B which takes to P3 and come back to P1 and click A its working,but button B is not.

I understand that an instance of that page is already running in the background. But don't know how to resume that page while clicking the button again.

Can anyone help with what should be done here?

Comment: "Not Working" means you cant navigate to the page?

Comment: and these 'Buttons' aren't in a ListBox, correct?

Comment: Actually A & B are the Values from the Long list Selector,the navigation is done in the Selection_changed event. I can navigate to the page but not continuously back to back.

Comment: See the answer I posted, I think it will resolve your issue

Comment: What code do you have on the SelectionChanged even handler?

Comment: Maxim V. Pavlov - Just the navigation code in the SelectionChanged event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are navigating via `SelectionChanged`, you need to reset the `SelectedIndex`:

```
public void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){

    var lb = (ListBox) sender;

    if (lb.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    //do your logic here
    NavigationService.Navigate(///);

    //reset selected index
    lb.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
```

Edit: `SelectedIndex` is not available in `LongListSelector`. Use `SelectedItem` instead.

```
void PersonSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (buddies.SelectedItem == null) return;
            Person person = buddies.SelectedItem as Person;
            if (person != null)
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Samples/PersonDetail.xaml?ID=" + person.ID, UriKind.Relative));
            }

            buddies.SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

Comment: The Selection is from LongListSelector control, i couldn't apply the above logic for that. Do you know how to reset the index in LongListSelector control?

Comment: Your using the Jumplist to navigate to new pages? It should be used to 'jump' to items in the list.

Comment: Let me know, I can look at the API if not

Comment: Hi - No am not using anything like Jumplist.I am just navigating to a page(P2) when a value is selected in the LonglistSelector in P1. Also am passing the value selected in P1 in the Navigation Service Link. I hope this is clear. I really appreciate your help ! Thanks

Comment: @Sri check out my updated post. Just tried it with the LongListSelector. (Taken from the Toolkit sample)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/P2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

to navigate to P2 given that P2.xaml is your P2 page.

Comment: Hi I'm able to navigate to the pages with the above code,but question is not that. Anyways thanks for responding !